# Does $f(t,y)=4t\sqrt{y}$ satisfy the Lipschitz Condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, lipschitz-functions

$f(t,y)=4t\sqrt{y}$.

**Does $f$ satisfy the  Lipschitz Condition?**

In other words how do I check if
$$|f(t, y_1) - f(t, y_2)| = |4t\sqrt{y_1} - 4t\sqrt{y_2}|
 \le C |y_1- y_2|$$
holds.

**EDIT**: My Domain is $0<t<b$ for some real positive constant $b$ and $0<y<\infty$

Comment: Triangle inequality on $|\sqrt{y_1} - \sqrt{y_2}|$ ?

Comment: @PackSciences Do you mean $|\sqrt{y_1}-\sqrt{y_2}|\le\sqrt{|y_1-y_2|}$?

Comment: Your notation seems unclear.  What is the function $y(t)$?

Comment: Hmm. It could be nice if people left a comment after a downvote,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the domain. $|\sqrt {y_1} -\sqrt {y_2}| \leq C|y_1-y_2|$ does not hold for $y_1$ and $y_2$ near $0$. Reason: for $y_1,y_2 >0$ we have $|y_1-y_2|=|\sqrt {y_1} -\sqrt {y_2}| |\sqrt {y_1} +\sqrt {y_2}|$. The inequality becomes $1 \leq C|\sqrt {y_1} +\sqrt {y_2}|$ which leads to a contradiction if you let $y_1,y_2 \to 0$.

Comment: I have edited my question. $y>0$

Comment: It is still  false.  @k.dkhk

Comment: So the conclusion to my question is: NO? It does not satisfy the Lipschitz Condition?

Comment: @k.dkhk Yes, that is the conclusion.

Comment: @k.dkhk  have added a justification.

Answer (score 0):

By use of the binomial theorem you get
$$
|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)|= 4|t|\frac{|y_1-y_2|}{\sqrt{y_1}+\sqrt{y_2}}.
$$
This, as has been observed multiple times, is unbounded if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are close to zero.